# Using a "shared" type on a WCF/MVC project with two services ("cannot convert from...")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I've two WCF services connected to my client. I want to use a User-object, retrieved from service #1, and use this as paramter for service #2. Here is my MVC-Controller `TournamentController.cs` code:

```
    private readonly GCTournamentServiceClient _tournamentClient = new GCTournamentServiceClient();

    public ActionResult Join(int id)
    {
        GCUserServiceClient userClient = new GCUserServiceClient();

        // Get current user
        var currentUser = userClient.GetUser(0);

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            // Get selected tournament
            var selectedTournament = _tournamentClient.GetTournament(id);

            // Check if there are available seats in the tournament
            if (selectedTournament.Seats > selectedTournament.RegistredUsers.Count)
            {
                // Check if user exist amoung registred users
                if (!selectedTournament.RegistredUsers.Contains(currentUser))
                {
                    selectedTournament?.RegistredUsers.Add(currentUser);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error Visual Studio prompt me with:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'GConnect.Clients.WebClient.GCUserService.User' to 'GConnect.Clients.WebClient.GCTournamentService.User'
```

So the problem is `currentUser`, which has the type GCUserService.User. I'm unable to use this as parameter for `RegistredUsers`

The error itself makes perfect sense, however, I'm not quite sure how I'm suppose to convert this type (properly). Some articles states, that a "shared"-service has to be created, which holds the User-type. I just can't believe, that a solution like that, should be necessary.

I might have misunderstood some basic stuff here (working with WCF and MVC), but please enlighten me, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

> So the problem is currentUser, which has the type GCUserService.User.
>   I'm unable to use this as parameter for RegistredUsers

There are 2 approaches to solve this problem:

**1)** 
Create a class library project (Visual Studio) and add the `User` class in that project, compile it and add its assembly's (.dll) reference to both services and the client (your MVC application). Next retrieve that user object as you are already doing it

```
var currentUser = userClient.GetUser(0);
```

GetUser will return the type of `User` that is defined in a separate assembly which is added as reference as suggested above. The `TournamentService` will also reference the same assembly and the `RegistredUsers.Add(User userToadd)` method will take the same `User` object and WCF runtime should be able to serialise/desterilise it.

**2)** 
In your MVC client application, new up the `User` object that is acceptable by the `TournamentService.RegistredUsers.Add` method. Populate its properties from the `currentUser` and pass in that object as parameter to `RegistredUsers.Add` method.

**Best Practice**

Ideally, I would recommend the first approach which is more work but a better practice and that your `User` class is maintained centrally and code is reused.

Hope this helps!